# Azure app service with FaceBook based authentication

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin

I am developing an app based on Azure App Service Mobile in Xamarin.Forms.

I looked at several samples, but did not find any solution to use Azure - FB authentication in XAMARIN.FORMS. Samples provided by Microsoft are only for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS, and could not find any Xamarin doc about it.

My question: is there any tutorial with FB authentication (with its UI related features) for Azure app service mobile FB authentication for Xamarin.Forms?

My FaceBook app itself is working, my Azure service is working, its FB settings are set, connection is OK, offline syncing working like a charm.

My main problem is about FB authentication features. I thought, it is some built in feature in MS MobileService component, or there is a straightforward solution in XF...but I found only hacky solutions so far.

Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it. When instantiating a MobileServiceClient for authentication use ApplicationKey instead of ApplicationURL as parameter. It solved all my problems for now. But why, I don't know.

So, use

```
var mobileServiceClient  = 
        new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://cs-northeurope-schedulerxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
            "https://cs-northeurope-schedulerxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
        );
```

Instead of

```
var mobileServiceClient = 
        new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://appname.azurewebsites.net",
            "https://cs-northeurope-schedulerxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
        );
```

when authenticating.

When offline data syncing, the normal parameters work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Quick question, are you using this SDK? https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb
Or this one? http://facebooksdk.net/
I run into a lot of issues with the last one as it had workarounds over workaround but the one from GIT was working like a charm. What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Pls. see my answer. Thanks!